# Why are questions which are closed not deleted, and why cannot the poster delete them after they are closed?

Tags: feature-request

Several questions that I have asked have been closed as too broad or for other reasons, after they have received an answer. Rather than leave them just taking up space I have tried to delete them but could not. After these questions have been closed in review I agreed with the comments and putting them on hold and being closed. However these questions which I agree are not fitting, are still being down voted. Should we not remove them when they are closed or at least block them for voting. Seems to me that we are subjecting people to continued punishment even after they have repented from their error, even God doesn't do that.

Answer (score 6):

The deletion rules are as follows:

- A question with no upvoted answers may be deleted by the OP at any time with a single click.
- A question can be deleted at any time by a moderator with a single click.
- A question that is closed, and severely negatively voted can be deleted by 3 10k users after a period of time or 3 20k users immediately.
- A question that is closed and not severely downvoted can be deleted by a specific number of 20k users related to the number of upvotes the question has (it starts at 3 and goes up from there).
- Old Closed questions with low scores (0 and less I think?) and no upvoted answers are cleaned up by an automated script that runs on a regular basis. If they've been edited recently they are excepted from this script.

Now, that means that more often than not a moderator's intervention is required to delete a question. If you have something specific that you'd like to delete, flag it and we'll take a look.

A few things that we should talk about when we get into this.

- The FAQ is pretty clear that if the question has good answers that it should stay, we don't like to lose content even if it's not really appropriate for the site.
- Questions that can be edited to make fit the sites format should be done so and reopened.
- Having a question closed is a normal part of site operations and should *not* be seen as a punitive action (nor should downvotes). Thinking of it as such is not a healthy way to think about how this site operates. If you're doing something wrong there are other means we will take of letting you know (now granted, if you're asking a *lot* of questions that get closed, then yeah, you'll likely hear from us about it, but the closure itself is not a punishment).
- Voting, even on closed questions is an important part of retaining site maintenance. It helps the deletion script if there are no upvoted answers, it helps remind folks that these are not good examples of questions, even though they aren't deleted on the site. Also limiting voting is really not supported for closed questions. We only have two tools for this, the first is deletion which is (at times) undesirable, and the second is locking which we generally don't do unless there is a good reason as it's tedious to maintain locks.

All that to say, if you've got specific questions you want to have cleaned up that you can't self delete, let us know and we'll take a look, but in general we are loathe to delete questions with good answers unless they are very clear poor fits. And please don't see closure or even downvotes as punitive but as content curation, that's the model here.

Comment: @ wax eagle whether intentional or not it is still a form of punishment, since most awards have to do with the number of positive reps one acquires, a down vote subtracts from one's total accumulation and thereby adds to ones consternation.

Comment: @CecilBeckum I agree, though it's not coincidental that at minimum upvotes outweigh downvotes 2.5-1.

Comment: @ wax eagle In that case would it make more sense to keep a running total of both separate?

Comment: No. We track upvotes and downvotes *given* publicly on people's profiles, but someone's reputation decreasing (either by receiving a downvote, an upvote being taken back, or an net rep-gain post being deleted) is hidden from the general public. This is to protect downvoters and the downvoted.

Comment: @ wax eagle understood, and after some consideration I agree. Maybe it is a good incentive to more carefully consider your posts.

Comment: @CecilBeckum Yep, that's the idea. The system is very well designed to enforce site policy (as defined by the community). A few down votes really aren't that bad. I've gotten plenty in the past. They upset me at first, then I make it a point to make a post that offsets them. I use it to encourage me to post better, not just in the future, but immediately.